# If ID is not in where list T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of ID's in my where clause and i want the query to return the ID's that are missing from this list

```
select distinct( b.PORTFOLIO_ID)
FROM [FIND].[dbo].[HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN] b
where b.PORTFOLIO_ID in (91,
93,
94,
95,
2010912563)
and b.HLDG_DATE='2017-05-05'
```

How can i obtain the list of ID's that are not yet loaded into the Database?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by IDs not yet loaded? Do you mean from your list here or a separate list of values? This is a simple select statement so if you are doing a comparison between two tables to check for missing IDs you will most likely need to LEFT JOIN with a WHERE [Column] IS NULL argument.

Answer (score 2):

If the ID doesn't exist the system can't create/return the row as the data isn't present.  So first we need to generate a table with your ID's and then outer join to the other table where no match is found (portfolio is null)

You can use a common table expression or you can use an inline view.  This uses the common table expression C:

```
WITH C (ID) AS (SELECT 91 UNION 
                SELECT 93 UNION 
                SELECT 94 UNION 
                SELECT 95 UNION
                SELECT 2010912563) C

SELECT C.ID
FROM C
LEFT JOIN [FIND].[dbo].[HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN] b
   on B.PORTFOLIO_ID = C.ID
  and B.HLDG_DATE=cast('2017-05-05' as date)
WHERE B.PORTFOLIO_ID is null
```

This uses the inline view:

```
SELECT C.ID
FROM (SELECT 91 UNION 
      SELECT 93 UNION 
      SELECT 94 UNION 
      SELECT 95 UNION
      SELECT 2010912563) C(ID)
LEFT JOIN [FIND].[dbo].[HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN] b
   on B.PORTFOLIO_ID = C.ID
  and B.HLDG_DATE=cast('2017-05-05' as date)
WHERE B.PORTFOLIO_ID is null
```

Comment: Beat me. But I dont think you need distinct.

Comment: True. Very true.

Comment: I'd say great minds think alike, but I'm not that great.

Comment: You can use [**VALUES**](http://rextester.com/CPHL39906)  instead of writing so many `UNION`  `SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (91), (93), (94), (95), (2010912563)
     ) as T(id)`

Comment: Old habits die hard.  then they die harder.. then they die with a vengeance.   So I just live free; and I'll die hard.

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way:

```
select v.PORTFOLIO_ID
from (values(91),(93),(94),(95),(2010912563))v(PORTFOLIO_ID)
    left outer join [FIND].[dbo].[HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN] b on b.PORTFOLIO_ID = v.PORTFOLIO_ID and b.HLDG_DATE='2017-05-05'
where b.PORTFOLIO_ID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your list Ids into a table and use `NOT EXISTS` like this

```
select * 
FROM (values (91),(93),(94),(95),(2010912563)) v(t)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [FIND].[dbo].[HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN] b 
                          WHERE b.PORTFOLIO_ID  = v.t 
                                and b.HLDG_DATE='2017-05-05' )
```

Comment: This bring up all other portfolio ID that i am not interested in

Comment: This will simply return all rows where the ID is not one of the ones specified.  So it could return where ID = 5.  How does this help find missing ID's?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you any IDs from your list that do not exist dbo.Holdings_Breakdown

```
create table #IDs(PORTFOLIO_ID int)
insert into #IDs(PORTFOLIO_ID) values(91),(93),(94),(95),(2010912563)

select a.PORTFOLIO_ID
from #ID a
left join [FIND].[dbo].[HOLDINGS_BREAKDOWN] b 
    on b.PORTFOLIO_ID = a.PORTFOLIO_ID
    and b.HLDG_DATE='2017-05-05'
where b.PORTFOLIO_ID is NULL
```

Comment: the where `and b.hldg_date='2017-05-05'` will negate the left join making it an inner the limiting criteria must be on the join. or this  will never return results!

Comment: Correct, forgot it completely the first time and pasted it back in the wrong place